# C# - DataGridView - Cannot Get ColumnCount, Cannot Get Cell Values

Tags: c#, datagridview

Based on how the DGV is being used, I cannot use binding to data. I'll post everything that is being done, in pretty much the order I am trying to do it. The problem is that when I try to hit SAVE, the method acts as if it has no idea who this "dataGridView1" character is, almost as if it's out of scope, but it's not out of scope.

```
private void RefreshDGV1(){ 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        string query = (@"
SELECT  HLD_ID      AS 'HLD_ID'             ,
    HoldName    AS 'Hold Name'          ,
    BeginDate   AS 'Begin Date'         ,
    FileNumber  AS 'File Number'        ,
    Operation   AS 'Operation'          ,
    Brand       AS 'Brand'              ,
    PAddress    AS 'Property Address'   ,
    Found       AS 'Found'              ,
    Match       AS 'Address Match'      ,
    Secured     AS 'File Secured'       ,
    Relocated   AS 'File Relocated'     ,
    Comment     AS 'Comment'
FROM    Records     
");
        //dataGridView1.DataSource       = bindingSource1;
        //dataGridView1.ColumnCount      = 11;

        //dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name    = "Hold Name";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn HoldName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        HoldName.HeaderText                = "Hold Name";
        HoldName.Name                      = "Hold Name";
        HoldName.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(HoldName);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name     = "Begin Date";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn BeginDate = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        BeginDate.HeaderText                = "Begin Date";
        BeginDate.Name                      = "Begin Date";
        BeginDate.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(BeginDate);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name      = "File Number";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn FileNumber = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        FileNumber.HeaderText                = "File Number";
        FileNumber.Name                      = "File Number";
        FileNumber.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(FileNumber);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name     = "Operation";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Operation = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        Operation.HeaderText                = "Operation";
        Operation.Name                      = "Operation";
        Operation.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Operation);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Brand";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Brand = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        Brand.HeaderText                = "Brand";
        Brand.Name                      = "Brand";
        Brand.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Brand);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name           = "Property Address";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PropertyAddress = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        PropertyAddress.HeaderText                = "Property Address";
        PropertyAddress.Name                      = "PropertyAddress";
        PropertyAddress.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(PropertyAddress);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name  = "Found";
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Found = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        Found.HeaderText                 = "Found";
        Found.Name                       = "Found";
        Found.Items.Add("");
        Found.Items.Add("Found");
        Found.Items.Add("Not Found");
        Found.Items.Add("In Progress");
        Found.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Found);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name         = "Address Match";
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn AddressMatch = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        AddressMatch.HeaderText                 = "Address Match";
        AddressMatch.Name                       = "Address Match";
        AddressMatch.Items.Add("");
        AddressMatch.Items.Add("Yes");
        AddressMatch.Items.Add("No");
        AddressMatch.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(AddressMatch);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name        = "File Secured";
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn FileSecured = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        FileSecured.HeaderText                 = "File Secured";
        FileSecured.Name                       = "File Secured";
        FileSecured.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(FileSecured);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name         = "File Relocated";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn FileRelocated = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        FileRelocated.HeaderText                = "File Relocated";
        FileRelocated.Name                      = "File Relocated";
        FileRelocated.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(FileRelocated);

        //dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name  = "Comment";
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Comment = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        Comment.HeaderText                = "Comment";
        Comment.Name                      = "Comment";
        Comment.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        Comment.Width = (dataGridView1.Width / 11);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Comment);

        //dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        //other stuff
        //dataGridView1.Columns[(dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1)].AutoSizeMode              = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns[(dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1)].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += handler_dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
        ReadSQL(query, dataGridView1);
    }
private void ReadSQL(string query, DataGridView grid){
        try{
            string connectionString = "Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD";
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            for(int i = 0 ;  i < table.Rows.Count; i++){
                int n = grid.Rows.Add();
                grid.ColumnCount = 11;
                InitializeComponent();

                //Add to ID array (list)
                RecordIDs.Add(table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());

                grid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                grid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                grid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                grid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                grid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                grid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[6].ToString();

                string selection1                         = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
                switch(selection1){
                    case "Found"       : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[1];}catch{}; break;
                    case "Not Found"   : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[2];}catch{}; break;
                    case "In Progress" : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[3];}catch{}; break;
                    default            : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];}catch{}; break;   
                }

                string selection2 = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();
                switch(selection2){
                    case "Yes" : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[1];}catch{}; break;
                    case "No"  : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[2];}catch{}; break;
                    default    : try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value  = (grid.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];}catch{}; break;
                }

                try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[9].ToString();}catch{}
                try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[10].ToString();}catch{}
                try{grid.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[11].ToString();}catch{}
            }

            LoadDGV1ToolTips();

            grid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            grid.RowHeadersVisible                       = false;
            grid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles               = false;
            grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
            grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            grid.GridColor                               = Color.RoyalBlue;

            for(int i = 0 ;  i < grid.Columns.Count; i++){
                grid.Columns[i].Width = (grid.Size.Width / grid.Columns.Count) - 1;
            }

        }catch(SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("SQL ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(query);
        }
    }

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ //SAVE
        string name      = "";
        string date      = "";
        string file      = "";
        string operation = "";
        string brand     = "";
        string address   = "";
        string found     = "";
        string match     = "";
        string secured   = "";
        string relocated = "";
        string comment   = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Column Count:      " + this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++){ 
            switch(i){
                //put some handlers in here for null values, try/catch?
                case  0: try{name      = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  1: try{date      = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  2: try{file      = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  3: try{operation = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  4: try{brand     = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  5: try{address   = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  6: try{found     = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  7: try{match     = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  8: try{secured   = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case  9: try{relocated = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                case 10: try{comment   = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString();}catch{}; break;
                default: break; //Do Nothing.
            }
        }
        if(secured != "True"){secured = "False";}
        string query = (@"
 UPDATE Records
 SET    HoldName = '" + name   + "', BeginDate = '" + date + "', FileNumber = '" + file + "', Operation = '" + operation + "', Brand = '" + brand + "', PAddress = '" + address + "', Found = '" + found + "', Match = '" + match + "', Secured = '" + secured + "', Relocated = '" + relocated + "', Comment = '" + comment + "'" + 
"WHERE  HLD_ID   = '" + HLD_ID + "'");
        //WriteSQL(query);
        Console.WriteLine("Query: " + query);
        RefreshDGV1();
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you first start using the debugger and try to pinpoint what line in your code you are having issues.. also is this a web app..? or a winforms app..? your code could use some serious refactoring and cleaning up as well I would also start reading up / researching on how to use the `using(){}` statement for all of your Sql objects as well as Cleaning up the `DataTable` objects.. personally I would declare that at the class level .. clean up your code formatting here as well very messy

Comment: also when you have a DataGridView, and you have the Query regardless of if returns Data or not.. you can get the column count based on the DataTable.Columns.Count once it's DataBind() method has been called.. also why do you have `InitializeComponent();` inside your ReadSQL() method`

Comment: I am not receiving an error for trying to get dataGridView1.ColumnCount, so what good is the debugger? This is a WinForms app using Visual Studio. Can you elaborate on "serious refactoring" and "cleaning up"? Not sure what you mean here. I am not worried about cleaning up the DataTable objects at this point, all I am trying to do is get this method to acknowledge the presence of the dataGridView, which it is not. Don't worry about what's outside of this, as it's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Also, code formatting? That's subjective and is a matter of opinion. I probably hate the fact that you most likely put your curly brackets on the next line, which I absolutely hate. Don't thumbs down my question when A) you don't have a reason and B) your feedback is not valuable at all. D- on your comment.

Comment: THIS: "why do you have InitializeComponent(); inside your ReadSQL() method"

Comment: I honestly probably looked over that a million times. I don't know why I never caught that. As soon as I commented it out, the problem went away. I actually remember the ADD button working, and then out of the blue, I had issues with SAVE. Makes no sense to me how this got here, but once again, you've saved the day. Kudos again, sir.

BTW: I am learning C# as my 9th language, but no formal C# or Visual Studio experience or training.

Comment: I've got several languages under my belt, which range from low level hardware languages all the way up to scripting and query languages. I guess my diverse influence has given me a little bit of an "accent" when I code, so I am sorry if you see this as sloppy. To be honest, the closest thing I have to C# is JAVA (which I hate with all my very soul), but no one in all of those classes really teaches you how to not be sloppy, which I think really comes from experience working with a team of other developers, which I have never done.

Comment: I've always coded my own projects, so I apologize if I appear to be a little "bushman" to you.

Comment: another suggestion would be to remove the dynamic sql from the code and put it in a stored procedure this way if you ever had to change this you would just change the stored procedure and not have to keep changing the code in your program. also I will post a freeB for you on how you should be calling your methods in regards to using the `.Fill()` method you can put this in one place and no matter how many different stored procedures you decide to create or call you will have only one method vs re-writing the same method over and over again

Comment: this is not a pissing contest.. I have tons more languages under my belt.. but that's neither here nor there.. I am trying to help you

Comment: Sorry Method, I was not flexing my muscles, I was just trying to justify my "bushman" nature to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102744/discussion-between-ryan-haley-and-methodman).

Comment: no problem.. look at the Sql Helper class I just posted for you to use.. it will make your life a lot easier trust me..

Comment: have a good weekend ..it's Miller Time by the looks of my watch.. cheers

Comment: cheers sir, and thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a static class that you could use to make calling stored procedures better perhaps you can utilize as well as learn from it

```
//If you want to return a DataSet
public static class SqlDBHelper
{
    public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw; trap for you exception(s) here
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }

    //if you want to return a DataTable       
    public static DataTable ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Show a message or log a message on ex.Message
            }
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: You should never use `throw ex` in that manner in the catch block. You should use `throw;` instead, as it preserves the call stack. But anyways such a low level call has no business catching and rethrowing the error, as at that level you can't possibly decide how to recover from the exception.